# How to add a animation to myPlayer

Tags: xna, animation, monogame, xna-content-pipeline

I'm currently making a shoot em up in monogame.

I want to add just one animation to my object. No commands or transitions between animations for different actions: just an object swapping between different images all the time.

For example, my player will have 4 different images for it and I'd want it to always swap trough these images.

Animation guides I've reviewed seem way too complicated for my needs. Unlike the examples they cover, I don't want different animations for different commands.

How can I make this type of simple, always-looping frame animation?

Edit

I managed to make a constantly looping animation to a sprite and but I don't know how to insert into myPlayer.

```
Game1:
        Texture2D myPlayerAnim;
        Rectangle myDestRect;
        Rectangle mySourceRect;
        Texture2D myEnemyAnim;
        Rectangle myEnemyDestRect;
        Rectangle myEnemySourceRect;
        float myElapsed;
        float myDelay = 100f;
        int myFrames = 0;

Initialize:
            myDestRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 512, 512);
            myEnemyDestRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 808, 608);

LoadContent: 

            myPlayerAnim = Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpriteSheetPlayerAnim");
            myEnemyAnim = Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpriteSheetEnemyAnim");

Update:    
            myElapsed += (float)aGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;

            if (myElapsed >= myDelay)
            {
                if (myFrames >= 3)
                {
                    myFrames = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    myFrames++;
                }
                myElapsed = 0;
            }

            mySourceRect = new Rectangle(512 * myFrames, 0, 512, 512);
            myEnemySourceRect = new Rectangle(808 * myFrames, 0, 808, 608);

Draw: 

            mySpriteBatch.Draw(myPlayerAnim, myDestRect , mySourceRect, 
            Color.White);
            mySpriteBatch.Draw(myEnemyAnim, myEnemyDestRect, myEnemySourceRect, 
            Color.White);´
```

Draw just draws the animations out but I don't know how to insert it into myPlayer. For myPlayer I currently have this but I couldn't figure out how to do it with my animations.

```
Draw: 
myPlayer = new Player(TextureLibrary.GetTexture("player"), myPlayerPos, 200, new Vector2(.3f, .3f), 0, Color.White, 1000, 1);
```

Comment: For beginners, I suggest that you get through the tutorial below first. [2D XNA Tutorials - RB Whitaker's Wiki](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-tutorials) Also your problem (which we call `texture atlases`) is lying in this link: [Texture Atlases - Part 1](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/texture-atlases-1) Just follow the tutorial from the beginning. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you have given. I think you just need to change some things.

First, use the `SpriteSheetPlayerAnim` as the texture of your player directly instead of using `player` texture.

Then move the code of `Update` and `Draw` of player's animation to `Update` and `Draw` of `Player` class.

They will be like this:

```
public class Player
{
    //Default constructor
    public Player()
    {
        //default values for your player//for example only
        //this.hp = 100;
        //this.mp = 20;
    }

    //Constructor
    public Player(GameTime myelapsedGameTime, Texture2D texPlayer, Vector2 playerPosition, int something, Vector2 vector2ForSomething, int intFST, Color playerColor, ...)
    {
        //initialise player's attributes

    }

    public override Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (myElapsed >= myDelay)
        {
            if (myFrames >= 3)
            {
                myFrames = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                myFrames++;
            }
            myElapsed = 0;
        }
    }

    public override Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(myPlayerAnim, myDestRect , mySourceRect, 
            Color.White);//for example
    }
}
```

Then in your `Game1` class:

```
public class Game1 : Game
{
    Player player;
    GameTime myElapsed;

    public Game1()
    {
        //
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        //Load your animated sprite here
        myPlayerAnim = Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpriteSheetPlayerAnim");

        player = new Player(myElapsed, myPlayerAnim, ...);//constructor with attributes here or whatever you want
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        myElapsed += (float)aGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        player.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        player.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

For beginners, I suggest that you get through the tutorial below first.

[2D XNA Tutorials - RB Whitaker's Wiki](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/2d-tutorials)

Also your problem (which we call `texture atlases`) is lying in this link:

[Texture Atlases - Part 1](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/texture-atlases-1)

Just follow the tutorial from the beginning. Hope this helps!